# Структура папок в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Есть ли какое то правило для строгого именования папок в Spring MVC. смотрел разные видео где использовали например папку dao, я так понимаю она нужна для хранения сушностей. можно ли вместо dao назвать например model. и так же с другими ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

model - папка для entity

dao / dto - папка для трансферных классов

controller - папка для контроллеров

service - папка для сервисов

repository - папка для репозиториев

Остальные папки именуйте в соответствии с их логическим назначением

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели сказать - пакеты

Comment: @dmtr человек спросил о папках - я ему так и написал; для большего понимания

Answer (score 2):

```
app..
     business.. - бизнес логика
               dao
               domain - модели
               service
     config..
     utils..
     web.....  
               dto
               api - контроллеры
```